# Censoring "Death" in Time-To-Recovery Analysis

Tags: survival, epidemiology, censoring

I am performing time-to-recovery analysis comparing 2 groups. In both groups, a few subjects died from the disease under consideration (instead of recovering). Is it appropriate to consider the deaths as right-censored data? I am concerned that I might introduce bias if I exclude deaths from the analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only removing those observations can bias the results but also right censoring can do so: will the dead subjects recover later? No! (Or the recovery will take an eternity.) Put differently, dying is a competing risk to your event of interest. In duration analysis, there are ways to deal with competing risks, see e.g.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_survival (or better search for a better reference. Wiki soes not seem to be very helpul for once).

If competing events are rare and also quite balanced across groups, then you don't have to worry much. The potential bias in any estimate $\hat \Delta$ of typical group differences will namely be negligible with either of your proposed strategy. But if most dead persons are belonging to one group, then you need to be careful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! That make sense. For those like myself who are using R, I found this useful introductory article on handling competing risks: http://www.nature.com/bmt/journal/v40/n4/full/1705727a.html

Comment: Thank you for the reference. The R library is nice, I've used it already in different cases.